# Difficult with structures C

Tags: c, function, pointers, structure

I'm dealing with a big code that makes massive use of structures to access variables in multiple void functions.  I was trying to write an code with the basic structure of the program just to know how can I deal with it without break it.

I wrote the code below with some questions can you guys help me ?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct useful_stuff
{

    int loop_var;  /* I want to use the loop_var in multiple void 
                * functions to iterate my loops
            */

}useful_stuff;

typedef struct leo_stuff
{

    int the_stuff;/* the stuff is a member I will use and modify
               *during the execution of the two void functions
               */

}leo_stuff;

void define_loop(useful_stuff u_s)  // This variable I want to use during the code
{
    u_s.loop_var = 10;   
}

void use_leo_stuff(useful_stuff u_s,leo_stuff *l_s)
{
    int i,loop;
    loop = u_s.loop_var;

    printf("the loop var is: %d\n", loop);

    for(i=0; i < loop; ++loop)
    {
        l_s.the_stuff = i + 1000;
        //(*l_s).the_stuff = i + 1000;  Is this more correct ?
        printf("l_s stuff from stuff1 is: %d\n",l_s.the_stuff);
        //here I'm expecting to see 1001,1002,1003.....
    }

}

//why he choosed to call a struct with simple declaration or with a pointer ?
void use_leo_stuff_again(useful_stuff u_s,leo_stuff *l_s)  
{
    int i,loop;
    loop = u_s.loop_var;

    printf("The loop var from again is: %d\n",loop);

    for(i=0; i<loop; ++i)
    { 
        l_s.the_stuff = i+1000;
        printf("the_stuff from again is: %d\n", the_stuff);
        //here I expect to see 2011,2012,2013 ...
    }

}

int main()
{
    useful_stuff u_s;  // Is this the correct way to call functions with 
                   //   structures in main ??
    leo_stuff *l_s;

    define_loop(useful_stuff u_s);

    use_leo_stuff(useful_stuff u_s,leo_stuff *l_s);

        use_leo_stuff_again(useful_stuff u_s,leo_stuff *l_s);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like to use the modified values of `useful_stuff` in other functions, you need to pass them using a pointer to `define_loop`.

The `leo_stuff` variable needs to be declared as a normal variable and then passed using the address of operator &.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is not so much due to difficulty with structs, rather it is in understanding the difference between passing a variable, or the address of the variable.

When you pass a variable as a function argument, the function receives a COPY of the variable, such that any changes made are only visible in the function. The value of the variable in the calling function (i.e. `main()`) remains unchanged.

To have the function actually change the value of the variable in memory, you must pass the variable ADDRESS (i.e. a pointer) as an argument to the function. Then any changes made to the value at that address are also available in `main()` (or the calling function).

Below is a tweak to your code reflecting this principle. It applies regardless of the type of data you are passing to the function. Let me know if you have questions.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct useful_stuff 
{
    int loop_var;

} useful_stuff;

typedef struct leo_stuff
{
    int the_stuff;

} leo_stuff;

/* to change the value in main(), you must pass the address
of u_s (i.e. a pointer to u_s) otherwise, the function just
gets a COPY of u_s, and the value in main() is unchanged
*/
void define_loop (useful_stuff *u_s)
{
    u_s->loop_var = 10;   
}


void use_leo_stuff (useful_stuff u_s, leo_stuff *l_s)
{
    int i = 0;
    int loop = 0;

    loop = u_s.loop_var;

    printf ("\nThe loop var is: %d\n\n", loop);

    for(i=0; i < loop; ++i)
    {
        l_s->the_stuff = i + 1000;

        printf("  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: %d\n",l_s->the_stuff);
    }
}

void use_leo_stuff_again (useful_stuff u_s, leo_stuff *l_s)  
{
    int i = 0;
    int loop = 0;

    loop = u_s.loop_var;

    printf("\nThe loop var from again is: %d\n\n",loop);

    /* l_s->the_stuff is still 1009 from the first funciton 
    let's do something different here, like reduce it to
    the original value
    */
    for(i=0; i<loop; ++i)
    { 
        printf("  the_stuff from again is: %d\n", l_s->the_stuff);
        l_s->the_stuff -= 1;
    }

}

int main()
{
    useful_stuff u_s;           /* declare an instance of u_s & stuff       */
    leo_stuff stuff;

    leo_stuff *l_s = &stuff;    /* then create your l_s pointer to stuff    */

    define_loop (&u_s);         /* pass the address to preserve the change  */

    use_leo_stuff (u_s, l_s);   /* call your functions as normal    */

    use_leo_stuff_again (u_s, l_s);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_ptrs

  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1000
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1001
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1002
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1003
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1004
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1005
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1006
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1007
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1008
  l_s stuff from stuff1 is: 1009

The loop var from again is: 10

  the_stuff from again is: 1009
  the_stuff from again is: 1008
  the_stuff from again is: 1007
  the_stuff from again is: 1006
  the_stuff from again is: 1005
  the_stuff from again is: 1004
  the_stuff from again is: 1003
  the_stuff from again is: 1002
  the_stuff from again is: 1001
  the_stuff from again is: 1000
```

Comment: Hold on, hit tab enter too soon.